# Why my transistor switched when base was grounded?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, transistors, batteries

I am from a programming background, so I dont quite know the theory, But I want to control a motor from a mictrocontroller. So I used a TIP 122 to do it. 
My circuit looks a bit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQVsra.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why did the motor run when I connected the base of the transistor to gnd? also, the motor runs at full speed even if I apply base voltage as low as .2 volts. What is going wrong here ?

I even tried adding a 500ohm resistors to base, but it still doesnt have any change.

Comment: You probably have the pinout wrong, and the motor is connected base to emitter. I'm surprised it's moving at all with a 1V supply.

Comment: my connection is something like this:http://www.instructables.com/id/Super-Easy-Reversible-Motor-Control-for-Arduino-/

Comment: Matt is referring to the transistor: you probably swapped base and collector.

Comment: Tip122 has the base as the leftmost pin, right ?if thats the case, then I am quite sure of that part

Comment: also, could anyone tell me if applying a  base voltage of about 2V will make the motor run at full speed ? my motor runs at around 12v at full speed

Comment: Don't apply 2V to the base in this configuration! You transistor will burn out! Connect a resistor to the base and apply the voltage to the resistor. Check the transistor datasheet; see what base current is required for the desired collector current to run the motor at full speed. Choose the base resistor accordingly.

Comment: ^i meant applying voltage to the resistor only

Comment: You know it's really not hard to put the correct supply voltage on the voltage source and rename the transistor to the right part.

Comment: I know , its as easy as overlooking it. Sorry anyway.

Comment: [TIP122 datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/TI/TIP122.pdf)

Comment: Make sure the heatsink tab isn't grounded... it's probably a collector connection.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this to drive your motor.  The 1k resistor must be tuned based on your motor's expected current for a given voltage.  Usually you have a spec like 500mA@12V or something of the like.

Basically, to get the 500mA spec, you want collector current of 500mA.  The base current is always Ib=Ic/Hfe.

Tip122's Hfe is min 1000, so you get 500µA for Ib.  You know on a BJT that Vbe is 1.3V for Tip122 at 500mA (see plot in datasheet).  So if you have a GPIOs voltage of Vgpio, you have a voltage of Vgpio-2.5V across R1.

Using Ohm's law you can find out R1 => R1=(Vgpio-Vbe)/(Ic/Hfe).

```
For a 3.3V Gpio R1=(3.3V-1,3V)/(500µA) = 4K
For a 5V Gpio R1=(5V-1.3V)/(500µA) = 7.4K
```

Those resistor values are upper bound values to get your full 500mA.  You should be using values around those.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fknTFo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now for your question about what is going on, I can't answer.  It is not very clear about what you did and you look like you are mixing thing up a little.

Comment: why have you written micro ampere?

Comment: because Hfe of transistor is the current gain: a BJT transistor is basically a current amplifier.  Hfe defines by how much the base current is amplified, which is the very point of using a transistor to drive loads in the first place.  TIP122 is darlington configuration and such configurations have very high gains such as 1000.  500mA/1000 = 500µA.

Comment: Great. You have intelligently chosen the motor symbol. Technically a speaker is a complex motor.

Comment: @Amit Hasan I must admit that I hadn't put much though in choosing the speaker, but why not ;)

Comment: why dont I get the praise too? ;)

Comment: I didn't even notice you used that -_-' lol

Comment: What a coincidence! I didn’t realize that too.  You both deserve the credit.